# No ethernet Ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: networking, server, ethernet

I have recently upgraded Ubuntu Server 18.04 to 20.04. 18.04 ran perfectly as an asterisk server.  When rebooted after the upgrade, there was no ethernet connection.  What is the solution to this not uncommon problem ?  This is a server installation with no GUI and a limited software installation.  No Network or ncurses.  If I wish to install them.  Where do I find my usb stick in the file system.  Asterisk installation is quite a challenge and I would rathe avoid a new install.

Comment: Check the output of `ip addr`.

Answer (score -1):

I am new to Ubuntu Server 20.04 and had the same problem. I was able to connect to the Internet by using an Ethernet cable directly between the Ubuntu host (a laptop which had an Ethernet port) and my router. Prior to this, I had edited the config file for networking (/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml) using sudo nano so that it read as follows:

network:
version: 2
renderer: NetworkManager
ethernets:
wlo1:
dhcp4:true
enps03:
dhcp4:true

Note that wlo1 is my wi-fi card and enps03 is the Ethernet port

On rebooting, I was now on my network and could download network-manager using sudo apt install network-manager (of course, you can also install any other software you think is missing)

I am STILL not able to activate my wi-fi card but I feel I am close to a solution on that - and at least using the Ethernet cable, I have access to any packages that I might need to resolve that issue as well.

Note: (1) your config file in /etc/network may have a different name but it should be the only .yaml file in that folder; (2) you can also download net-tools (sudo apt install net-tools) which gives you access to the more familiar commands ifconfig, etc.

I hope this helps.

Comment: My noobieness is showing. The yaml file is not properly indented and the wi-fi entry - wlo1:, followed by dhcp4:true, should be under a separate section named "wifis", not under "ethernets". The main idea I was trying to get across was to use a wired Ethernet connection to enable you to download the packages you need in order to set up the wifi connection.